# In framework web2UI can't select or edit rows

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, user-interface, w2ui

In my header I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://w2ui.com/src/w2ui-1.4.3.min.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w2ui.com/src/w2ui-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

But if I add by toolbar new row - all working good !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Framework web2ui required in grid as id field with name "recid", but I made mistake and send data with field "recID" ...